# if else condition in html to check variable is empty

Tags: python, html

I'm trying include if and else conditions in html to check variable is null or not.But how to end else section in html

```
{% if abs==' ' %}
<p>SORRY NO ABSTRACT IN UPLOADED FILE</p>
{% else %}
<p>{{ abs  }}</p>
{%endelse%}
```

Comment: try: {% endif %} which templating language you are using?

Comment: There is not if/else condition in HTML. You must be using some templating language. Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: it looks like flask , use {% endif %} , refer this  link for more details - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/

Comment: HTML is a markup language, there is no conditional statements on it. Please specify which programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code and [this programming language detector](https://creativetechguy.com/utilities/codedetector) says, it is a Python syntax. Please make sure you specify the context of your question next time so it is better received by the community.

In Python, conditional statements are closed by a `{%endif%}` and you are using `{%endelse%}`.

The correct syntax would be:

```py
{% if abs==' ' %}
   <p>SORRY NO ABSTRACT IN UPLOADED FILE</p>
{% else %}
   <p>{{ abs  }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

This will only work if the condition you provided in your question example is the one you need.

Here is an article that you would like to read:

[Conditional if statement in a template.](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-add-an-if-statement-to-a-template-in-Django.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check Variable in Jinja2
Check if variable is defined (exists):

```
{% if variable is defined %}
    variable is defined
{% else %}
    variable is not defined
{% endif %}
```

Check if variable is empty:

```
{% if variable|length %}
    variable is not empty
{% else %}
    variable is empty
{% endif %}
```

Check if variable is true:

```
{% if variable is sameas true %}
    variable is true
{% else %}
    variable is not true
{% endif %}
```

Check if variable is defined and not empty:

```
{% if variable is defined and variable|length %}
    variable is defined and not empty
{% else %}
    variable is not defined or empty
{% endif %}
```

Check if variable is defined and true:

```
{% if variable is defined and variable is sameas true %}
    variable is defined and true
{% else %}
    variable is not defined or not set to true
{% endif %}
```

font: https://www.shellhacks.com/jinja2-check-if-variable-empty-exists-defined-true/